# Insert text before and after the selection in a textarea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I insert text before and after the selection in a *[textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)* with JavaScript?

Selection occurs into a *textarea* field of an HTML form.

Comment: Do you need broad browser support or will the modern browsers suffice (in other words, no IE at least until 9 comes out)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var selectionText = yourTextarea.value.substr(yourTextarea.selectionStart, yourTextarea.selectionEnd);
yourTextarea.value = "Text before" + selectionText + "Text after";
```

If you want to search and replace, then the following code will do the trick (in non-Internet Explorer browsers):

```
var textBeforeSelection = yourTextarea.value.substr(0, yourTextarea.selectionStart);
var textAfterSelection = yourTextarea.value.substr(yourTextarea.selectionEnd, yourTextarea.value.length);
yourTextarea.value = textBeforeSelection + " new selection text " + textAfterSelection;
```

Comment: You'll need to do something else for IE if you want to support it.

Comment: I think the sample above will replace the whole textarea content... maybe there's a way to search & replace?

Comment: If you want to search + replace then you could just read the text until the selection and then the one until the end. I will edit the abov answer to show you exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Riccardo: No, jQuery doesn't handle this, although there are jQuery plug-ins that do.

Answer (score 7):

Her us a simple script that works in both Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome, where myField is a object reference. It was assembled by several scripts found through the web.

```
function insertAtCursor(myField, myValueBefore, myValueAfter) {

    if (document.selection) {

        myField.focus();
        document.selection.createRange().text = myValueBefore + document.selection.createRange().text + myValueAfter;

    } else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {

        var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
        var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
        myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValueBefore + myField.value.substring(startPos, endPos) + myValueAfter + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: However it doesn't place the cursor after the closing tags when it's done.

Comment: For those who are looking for to focus the caret inside the textarea, `myField.focus(); myField.selectionStart = startPos + myValueBefore.length;  myField.selectionEnd = endPos + myValueBefore.length;` insert this code inside the 'if else' condition at the end.