# Use javascript to surround selected text in a textarea

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert text before and after selection in textarea with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714192/insert-text-before-and-after-selection-in-textarea-with-javascript)

I need some help writing a script that will surround selected text in a textarea.

Example

```
abc 123 xyz 789
```

I select 123 and then click a button that runs my script. The output should become:

```
abc <b>123</b> xyz 789
```

Comment: Have you checked these links: http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp, http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/formatting-selected-text-in-a-texterea-w-javascript-71157.html ?